# ArrayList access value

Tags: java, arraylist

In order to get the maximum and the minimum value in a `ArrayList` I wrote the following code:

```
public void SAW_Old(Service_Abstract Abstract) {
    ArrayList<Service_concrete> list = Abstract.getListcand();
    SerMin = new Service_concrete();
    Abstract.getMin_QoS(list);
    System.out.println("responseTimeMin: " + SerMin.getResponse_Time() + "/" + SerMin.getLatency());
    SerMax = new Service_concrete();
    SerMax = Service_Abstract.getMax_QoS(list);
    System.out.println("responseTimeMin: " + SerMax.getResponse_Time() + "/" + SerMax.getLatency());
}
```

`here is the source code of the getMax_QoS() :`

```
`public Service_concrete getMax_QoS(ArrayList<Service_concrete> list1) {
Service_concrete ServiceMax = new Service_concrete();
ServiceMax = list1.get(0);
System.out.println("Service Max" + list1.size());
for (int i = 1; i < list1.size(); i++) {
   //             ResponseTime
    if (ServiceMax.getResponse_Time() <= list1.get(i).getResponse_Time()) {
        ServiceMax.setResponse_Time(list1.get(i).getResponse_Time());
    }
    // availability
    if (ServiceMax.getAvailability() <= list1.get(i).getAvailability())     {
        ServiceMax.setAvailability(list1.get(i).getAvailability());
    }
    // Latency
    if (ServiceMax.getLatency() <= list1.get(i).getLatency()) {
        ServiceMax.setLatency(list1.get(i).getLatency());
    }
    // Reliability

    if (ServiceMax.getReliability() <= list1.get(i).getReliability()) {
        ServiceMax.setReliability(list1.get(i).getReliability());
    }
    // Succesibility 
    if (ServiceMax.getSuccessability() <= list1.get(i).getSuccessability())      {
        ServiceMax.setSuccessability(list1.get(i).getSuccessability());
    }
    // throughput 
    if (ServiceMax.getThroughput() <= list1.get(i).getThroughput()) {
        ServiceMax.setThroughput(list1.get(i).getThroughput());
    }
    // contextUser
    if (ServiceMax.getContextUser() <= list1.get(i).getContextUser()) {
        ServiceMax.setContextUser(list1.get(i).getContextUser());
    }
  }

   return ServiceMax;
```

}

Where `Service_Abstract.getMaxQoS()` return a new `Service_conrete` given the max values and `Service_Abstract.getMinQos()` return the minimum values.

But what I got after execution is the same value. Here is the program compilation:

```
Service Min:64.0
Service Min:58.0
Service Max:58.0---353.26
Service Max:353.26
Service Max:353.26---597.5
Service Max:597.5
Service Max:597.5---994.26
Service Max:994.26
Service Max:994.26---1442.86
Service Max:1442.86
Service Max:1442.86---2938.5
Service Max:2938.5
responseTimeMin: 2938.5/865.29
```

Comment: And what is the code under `getMin_QoS` and `getMax_QoS` ?

Comment: Also,, you never reasignate `SerMin` it will be stuck on the new `Service_concrete`

Comment: In addition if you don't use new memory every time you add to a list you are repeating objects

Comment: @litelite please what do you mean with reasignate what should I do ?

Comment: @efekctive actualy I'm not adding to the list I want just read element in it and keep max values

Comment: @Hedouda you are not taking the result of `Abstract.getMin_QoS(list);` (I assume it returns something because it seems that `getMax_QoS` does it like that)

Comment: @litelite I do it like you said but nothing is change,  it gives the same value in SerMax.getResponseTime() and for SerMin.getResponseTime() which is wrong

Comment: here is the response after changes: responseTimeMin: 2938.5/865.29
responseTimeMax: 2938.5/865.29

Comment: Whoever is adding is adding the same objects over and over, the is why you retrieve repeated value(s)